# ItemTemplate: ListBox vs ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemscontrol, itemtemplate

I'm quite new to the WPF world and I'm having some problems with templating items in an *ItemsControl*. What I need is to template elements (mostly buttons) inside an *ItemsControl* (or the like).

If I'm using the following XAML code ...

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border BorderBrush="AliceBlue" 
                        BorderThickness="3">
                    <TextBlock Text="Templated!"/>        
                </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <Button>Not templated</Button>
    <TextBlock>Text not templated</TextBlock>
</ItemsControl>
```

... I get this result: http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/2167/itemscontrolnottemplate.gif

The *ItemsControl* did not apply the template to either the *Button* nor to the *TextBlock* control. If I change the *ItemsControl* into a *ListBox* like this:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border BorderBrush="AliceBlue" 
                        BorderThickness="3">
                    <TextBlock Text="Templated!"/>        
                </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <Button>Not templated</Button>
    <TextBlock>Text not templated</TextBlock>
</ListBox>
```

... then I'm getting this result: img814.imageshack.us/img814/6204/listboxtoomuchtemplatin.gif

Now the template is applied to **BOTH** the child controls (even while I set the *DataType* to be *Button* only).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's difficult to infer what you're trying to do, but see if this helps...

A plain old `ItemsControl` won't wrap its children in a container if they're already UI elements. A `ListBox`, on the other hand, requires its children to be wrapped in a `ListBoxItem`.

If the item is wrapped, then the `ItemTemplate` will be applied. If the item is not wrapped, the `ItemTemplate` may as well not exist.

You almost always want to be adding *data* items to your `ItemsControl`, not UI elements. You then associate `DataTemplate`s with those data elements to define what UI elements are used to render them.

I think explaining your end goal would be necessary to help further.